# Navigating Tabs in ionic

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Tabs status , chats and accounts were already there and work fine and I added Slide.

I suppose all I needed to do was add a ion tab in tabs.html and define the state with url in app.js.

However, it is not able to find and load it. What looks wrong here?

My tabs.html looks like this:

```
<!--
Create tabs with an icon and label, using the tabs-positive style.
Each tab's child <ion-nav-view> directive will have its own
navigation history that also transitions its views in and out.
-->
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!--Practice Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Slide" icon-off="ion-ios-arrow-forward " icon-on="ion-ios-arrow-forward-utline" href="#/tab/events">
  <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

app.js looks like this:

```
  // Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $stateProvider
     .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html"
      })

      .state('app.events', {
        url: "/events",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/events.html"
          }
        }
      })

      .state('app.event', {
        url: "/events/:id",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/event.html"
          }
        }
      })

      .state('app.conference', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/conference.html"
          }
        }
      })

      .state('app.conference.information', {
        url: "/events/:id/conferences/:conferenceId/information",
        views: {
          'conferenceInformation': {
            templateUrl: "templates/conference/information.html"
          }
        }
      })

      .state('app.conference.presentation', {
        url: "/events/:id/conferences/:conferenceId/presentation",
        views: {
          'conferencePresentation': {
            templateUrl: "templates/conference/presentation.html"
          }
        }
      });




  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

Comment: use the key F12 if your using Firefox or Chrome and share the error you get in console

Comment: No error. It gets redirected to the default one which is tab-dash

Comment: I don't see a state defined for tab-menu in your app.js. Is this code latest? As you said it, you know you have to add a route, still that's missing in the code u posted :)

Comment: @Pavitar: Could you please check the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't setup a state for your new tab in `$stateProvider`.

### tabs.html

```
<ion-tab title="Slide" icon-off="ion-ios-arrow-forward " icon-on="ion-ios-arrow-forward-utline" href="#/tab/sliders">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-sliders"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

### app.js

```
.state('tab.sliders', {
  url: '/sliders',
  views: {
    'tab-sliders': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-sliders.html',
      controller: 'SlidersCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```